# How can I show that the unique fixed point of a composition of continuous functions implies another unique fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

Consider the continuous functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Is it possible to show that, if there exists a unique $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $x_0 = f(g(x_0))$, then there exists a unique $y_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $y_0 = g(f(y_0))$?

The proof of the existence of a fixed point $y_0$ of $g \circ f$ is straightforward. Because $x_0 = f(g(x_0))$, then $g(x_0) = g(f(g(x_0))$. Then, we let $y_0 = g(x_0)$, such that $y_0 = g(f(y_0))$, as desired. However, I can't yet prove the uniqueness of $y_0$, so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can push that a step further, and note that $x_1 = f(y_0)$ is a fixed point of $f$. That means that $x_1 = x_0$, by the uniqueness. Whether this gets you anywhere isn't clear to me, but I'll just note that you haven't used continuity yet, or the fact that the domain/codomain of each function is $\mathbb R$ rather than, say, $S^3$. You might see whether on some small finite set there's a counterexample, as a way or understanding what about continuity (or perhaps connectedness, or arc-connectedness) is important.

Comment: @JohnHughes Am I missing something? Why would it hold that $f(g(x_0)) = g(x_0)$?

Comment: @JohnHughes this actually came up as part of my research, and so this question is a simplified version of a part of my research. I added in the continuity assumption because it also exists in the more complicated version, and I thought that it would be helpful. I'm not yet sure if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically what John Hughes said in the comments. If $y_0, y_1$ were two fixed points of $g\circ f$ then your argument would give two fixed points of $f \circ g$, given by
$$
x_0 = f(y_0), x_1 = f(y_1).
$$
If $f \circ g$ has a unique fixed point then $x_0 = x_1$ but then
$$
y_0 = gf(y_0) = gf(y_1) = y_1
$$

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding of your argument: we first assume that $x_0 = f(g(x_0))$. From this, we get the fixed point $y_0 = g(x_0)$ of $g \circ f$. Then, we assume that there exists a $y_1 \neq y_0$ such that $y_1 = g(f(y_1))$. However, at this point, I'm not sure how you conclude that $f(y_1)$ is a fixed point of $f \circ g$ (from which you would conclude uniqueness). Could you please expand on this a bit more?

Comment: It's the same argument: if $y_1=gf(y_1)$ then applying $f$ gives $f(y_1) = fgf(y_1)$

Comment: Here's a general lemma: Suppose $p$ and $q$ are functions, and ( * ) $p \circ q (b) = b$, i.e., $b$ is a fixed point of $p \circ q$. Let $c = q(b)$.  Then applying $q$ to both sides of ( * ) we get $q(b) = q(p(q(b))$, so (**) **$q(b)$ is a fixed point of $q \circ p$**. Your initial statement applied this lemma in the case $p = f, q = g, b = x_0$. Holmes applies it to the case $p = g, q = f, b = f(x_0)$.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. It seems that continuity of $f$ and $g$ is not needed after all.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Holmes' helpful answer, here is a complete proof that generalizes the statement in the question.

Consider the (not necessarily continuous) functions $f : X_f \to Y_f$ and $g : X_g \to Y_g$, where $X_f,X_g,Y_f,$ and $Y_g$ are arbitrary sets. Consider the function composition $f \circ g : X_g \to Y_f$, and suppose that there exists a unique fixed point $x_0 \in X_g$ of $f \circ g$, such that $x_0 = f(g(x_0))$. We want to show that there exists a unique fixed point $y_0 \in X_f$ of the function composition $g \circ f : X_f \to Y_g$, such that $y_0 = g(f(y_0))$.

First, we show that $y_0$ exists. Because $x_0 = f(g(x_0))$, then $g(x_0) = g(f(g(x_0)))$ (this stems from the [univalence (a.k.a "right-uniqueness")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Specific_types_of_binary_relations) property of functions). Then, let $y_0 = g(x_0)$, such that $y_0 = g(f(y_0))$, as desired.

Next, we show that $y_0$ is unique. Suppose that there exists $y_1 \in X_f$ such that $y_1 \neq y_0$ and $y_1 = g(f(y_1))$. Because $y_1 = g(f(y_1))$, then $f(y_1) = f(g(f(y_1)))$, such that $f(y_1)$ is a fixed point of $f \circ g$. Similarly, because $y_0 = g(f(y_0))$, then $f(y_0)$ is also a fixed point of $f \circ g$. However, by assumption, $f \circ g$ has a unique fixed point $x_0$, and so it must be the case that $f(y_1) = f(y_0)$, which implies that $g(f(y_1)) = g(f(y_0))$. Finally, because $y_0$ and $y_1$ are both fixed points of $g \circ f$, then $y_1 = y_0$, as desired.

Additionally, by symmetry, we can repeat a variation of the proof above to prove the converse statement: if there exists a unique fixed point $y_0 \in X_f$ of $g \circ f$, such that $y_0 = g(f(y_0))$, then there exists a unique fixed point $x_0 \in X_g$ of $f \circ g$, such that $x_0 = f(g(x_0))$.

In conclusion, there exists a unique fixed point $x_0 \in X_g$ of $f \circ g$ if and only if there exists a unique fixed point $y_0 \in X_f$ of $g \circ f$.